# Gherkin syntax for windows desktop application test automation

Tags: automated-tests, bdd

Is there any solution, tool or framework to build a test automation project with Behavior Driven Development (BDD) approach for windows desktop application?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I prefer ruby for it but it also could be C# or something else. It depends on solution options.

Comment: As I know all the possible solutions are based on mixing between the following engines; Test runners, Gherkins parser and UI interaction FW/Win API.
This the case in C/++/#, Java, Python. I don't know ruby and it's FW, but I believe that it is the same case...
I can post an answer about the tools we have been used when I was in the .net world for doing such a tests.

Comment: I've used [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) in Video desktop (Win) player test automation. Works like a charm, easy to setup and use. Integrating it with BDD, such as Behave.

Comment: SpecFlow for C#

Comment: @DenisKoreyba is it working for winforms or desktop applications? Have you experienced it?

Comment: @buurkeey it is actually not connected - you use SpecFlow with any other technology you want. You can use it with MS test or with nUnit. You can use it with Selenium, TestStack.White, Coded UI or what ever you want. I used it with TestStack.White but again, it doesn't matter. Yes, you can use it for Automation of a desktop app. It's much more valuable what framework you'll choose to automate your app.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK most of the BDD frameworks falls under unit/whitebox testing framework, provides you a way to author test in BDD, providing step implementation and runner. What you are looking for is black box testing which requires to integrate unit test framework with respective tool/library/framework for example [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) for web, [Appium](http://appium.io/) for mobile. Appium also started support for [Windows](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/). So you can check if it satisfies your need.

If that is the case you can use [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which provides all you need for black box testing of web, mobile or web-services including:

- Integration with TestNG (popular Java unit testing framework) and selenium, Appium.
- Test authoring BDD or Keyword driven or Coded
- Detailed Reporting
- And many more.

All you need to start locating elements and write bdd using inbuilt steps for selenium and appium like:

```
Given send keys 'some text' into 'my.textbox'
when click on 'button.element'
Then verify 'another.element' is present
And verify 'another.element' text is 'some text'
```

Comment: The statement "most of the BDD frameworks falls under unit/whitebox" is false. BDD does not dictate whitebox/blackbox. There are plenty of frameworks that allow one to write Gherkin to execute Selenium or Appium commands.

Wikipedia: "This definition is rather non-specific in that it allows tests in terms of high-level software requirements, low-level technical details or anything in between."